# DTExec returns The package path referenced an object that cannot be found

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, dtexec

I have a SSIS package and am trying to execute it using DTExec.exe

My command is this:

```
DTExec /F \\SERVERNAME\CUBEDAILYBACKUP.DTSX /MAXCONCURRENT "-1" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING EWCPI /CONSOLELOG SMT /SET \PACKAGE.VARIABLES[BackupPath].VALUE;\\SERVERNAME\CUBESBACKUP
```

and I get error:

> .... The package path referenced an object that cannot be found:
>   "\PACKAGE.VARIABLES[BackupPath].VALUE". This occurs when an attempt is
>   made to resolve a package path to an object that cannot be found. ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using upper case:

you need to write `Package.Variables` instead of `PACKAGE.VARIABLES`

Also use  `.Value` instead of `.VALUE`